# Inner join with H2 database and fulltextsearch

Tags: java, sql, full-text-search, inner-join, h2

I've a table "BANKRECORDING" and it contains IDs references to differents tables.

This table is stored in H2 Databse and I use the fulltextsearch method.

For example I've a this "BANKRECORDING" :

```
ID | ID_LIBELLE | ID_PAYMENT
1  | 2          | 3
2  | 2          | 10
```

With simple query my inner join works. But in this query I don't know how to do :

```
SELECT B.* 
FROM FT_SEARCH_DATA(1, 0, 0) FT, 
BANKRECORDING B 
WHERE FT.TABLE='BANKRECORDING' AND B.ID=FT.KEYS[0]
```

It returns all my result but with IDs...

I've tried this but it returns so many results... A line by elements stored in my databse.

```
SELECT B.*, L.*, ET.*, P.*, MO.* 
FROM FT_SEARCH_DATA('car', 0, 0) FT, 
BANKRECORDING B, LIBELLE L, ETAT ET, PAYMENT P, MOTIF MO
WHERE FT.TABLE='BANKRECORDING' AND B.ID=FT.KEYS[0]
```

Someone know how to do INNER JOIN in this query ?

EDIT :

Desired output :

```
ID | ID_LIBELLE | ID_PAYMENT
1  | car         | bank check
2  | car         | transfer
```

Comment: Can you show the desired output?

Comment: It's probably a good idea to translate code samples into English. It's a little difficult to reason about a data model with names we don't understand.

Comment: oops... sorry it's change in my example output data

Comment: I see. Didn't know about such tool, will read about it. You may want to add this link to the question btw.

Comment: Sorry, just talk about "This table is stored in H2 Databse and I use the fulltextsearch method." Not very clear, I know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh ! Thanks to Andrew I've found how it's works ! In fact, to show data we must specify each element in our SELECT :

```
SELECT b.id, l.libelle, p.libelle
  FROM FT_SEARCH_DATA(1, 0, 0) FT, ENREGISTREMENT b
   JOIN LIBELLE l on (b.id_libelle = l.id)
   JOIN MODEREGLEMENT p on (b.id_MODEREGLEMENT = p.id)
 WHERE b.id=FT.KEYS[0]
 AND FT.TABLE='ENREGISTREMENT' 
ORDER BY b.id;
```

I dont know why we can't call "b.*" for elements...